# How to check first radiobutton in group

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I dynamically create a collection of `radiobuton`s.

```
<ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RadioButton GroupName="CurrentParameter"
                     IsChecked="{Binding IsSelected, Mode=TwoWay}"
                     Content="{Binding Name, Mode=OneWay}"/>
    </DataTemplate>
</ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
```

How can I set first of them to `IsChecked=true` by default? Ideally will be to do it in `xaml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should set the corresponding `IsSelected` source property to `true` in your view model.

**View:**

```
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding YourItemsSourceCollection}" ... />
```

**View Model:**

```
YourItemsSourceCollection[0].IsSelected = true;
```

That's how MVVM and data binding works. You set the initial value of the property that the `CheckBox` in the view binds to. The XAML markup shouldn't contain any logic that decides which value is selected initially. This logic belongs to the view model.

Comment: I.e. I can not to set "who" is first checked only by `xaml`'s tools?

Comment: @EgoPingvina your best bet, and cleaner solution, is to use the VM to set the first one to IsSelected = true. Otherwise you're going against the grain.

Comment: @EgoPingvina: As mentioned, you don't specify which item(s) to be initally selected in the XAML markup. XAML is a *markup* language and not a programming language. Please remember to accept the answer if your original question has been answered.